# How to get first value by alphabet from array or order that array by alphabet?

Tags: arrays, sorting, fortran, min

I have character array with surnames

```
character(SNAME_LEN, kind=CH_) :: Surnames(SNAME_AMOUNT) = ""
```

and I must to write minimal surname by alphabet to the file.

---

I can't to find function for my problem. Fortran has regular function MINVAL, but array for his must be INTEGER or REAL only.

Thanks for anything ideas :-)

UPD:
GFortran shows error

```sh
src/main.f90:73:22:

    write (*,*) MINVAL(Surnames(:))
                      1
Error: ‘array’ argument of ‘minval’ intrinsic at (1) must be INTEGER or REAL
```

UPD2:
The main part of program

lr1.f90

```
program lr1_1

    implicit none
    integer, parameter      :: CH_= Selected_Char_Kind("ISO_10646")
    character(*), parameter :: E_ = "UTF-8"

    integer, parameter :: SNAME_AMOUNT = 23, SNAME_LEN = 15, TEL_LEN = 10

    character(:), allocatable :: input_file, output_file

    character(SNAME_LEN, kind=CH_) :: Surnames(SNAME_AMOUNT) = ""
    character(TEL_LEN, kind=CH_) :: Tel(SNAME_AMOUNT) = ""

    integer :: In, Out, IO, i, j

    input_file = "input.txt"
    output_file = "output.txt"

    open (file=input_file, encoding=E_, newunit=In)
       read (In, '(3(a), 3(a))', iostat=IO) (Surnames(i), Tel(i), i = 1, SNAME_AMOUNT)
    close (In)

    write (*,*) MINVAL(Surnames(:))

end program lr1_1
```

input.txt

```
Дудиков         9111630001
Тихонов         9111630002
Степин          9111630003
Садовникова     9111630004
Воробъёва       9111630005
Дудиков         9111630006
Тихонов         9111630007
Степин          9111630008
Садовникова     9111630009
Воробъёва       9111630010
Петров          9111630011
Фёдоров         9111630012
Петров          9111630013
Воробъёва       9111630014
```

Comment: Actually `minval` is defined to work on character arrays too.

Comment: But check that the collating sequence suits your needs.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Unfortunately, not. GFortran shows error: `Error: ‘array’ argument of ‘minval’ intrinsic at (1) must be INTEGER or REAL`

Comment: As I understand it that's a bug in gfortran, but my copy of MR&C is far away so I can't be sure. Can you edit your question to show exactly what you are doing?

Comment: @IanBush Done. I will add sorting by phone number and writing to output file.

Comment: Best make a [mcve], a really small pieace of code that we can try to compile and see the errors. We cannot try to compile your code, it is not complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing `MINVAL` for the character type was tracked in bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36313 It is a new feature of Fortran 2003, in Fortran 95 these functions were only for real and integer. Update your compiler to GCC version 8 or more recent.

```
> cat minvalchar.f90 
print *,minval(["a"])
end
> gfortran-8 minvalchar.f90 
> ./a.out 
 a
```

Be aware that this method may not use the collating sequence you might need for your language:

```
print *,maxval([character(4) :: "a","b","c","č","d","ď","e","é","f"])
end

> ./a.out 
 ď
```

Especially considering that the file you now posted uses Cyrillic. I have no idea if the characters you need are correctly ordered in Unicode. You might need to use USC-4 in Fortran and even then the order may be unsuitable.

Comment: Yes, this looking nice. Error was fixed. But if I use my array (not test array), function return nothing... `write (Out, '(a)', iostat=IO) MINVAL(Surnames)`

Comment: And what is the value of `IO`? Just remove the iostat for a short time. If you use `iostat=` you MUST check the value. Please do read the disclaimer. This method may well be **un**suitable for Cyrillic.

Comment: Don't worry about Cyrillic, I tested this by test array and that was correctly `write (Out, '(a)', iostat=IO) MINVAL(["В", "Г", "А", "Б"])`

Comment: Ok, but you must check the iostat value.

Comment: Yes, I deleted `IO` and tried to just write to terminal `write (*,*) MINVAL(Surnames)`, but I have empty only.